# Bring a specific fragment to top of other fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can I bring `fragment` to top of other `fragments` ?

I added `fragment` like bellow :

```
@OnClick(R.id.imbEvents)
void clickEvents() {
    String tagName = returnStatusFragment(getString(R.string.events_fragment));
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(tagName) && tagName.equals(getString(R.string.events_fragment))) {
        //Fragment is opened
    } else {
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            frameWorkTableFragment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            EventsFragment eventsFragment = new EventsFragment();
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_work_table_fragment,
                            eventsFragment,
                            getString(R.string.events_fragment))
                    .addToBackStack(getString(R.string.events_fragment))
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

I used from bellow code to bring `fragment` to top but close all last `fragments`:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(tagName, 0);
```

Method of `returnStatusFragment` is :

```
private String returnStatusFragment(String tagName) {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment tempFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tagName);
    if (tempFragment != null) {
        return tempFragment.getTag();
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

My `doBackTabZero`:

```
@Override
public void doBackTabZero(String nameFragment) {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManagers = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    Log.i("ASDSADASDSASD", "3 " + nameFragment + " " + fragmentManagers.getBackStackEntryCount());
    if (fragmentManagers.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
        fragmentManagers.popBackStackImmediate();
    } else {
        if (nameFragment.equals("EventsFragment")) {
            BusDisplayStatusFrameLayout busDisplayStatusFrameLayout = new BusDisplayStatusFrameLayout();
            busDisplayStatusFrameLayout.setDisplayStatusFrameLayout(1);
            EventBus.getDefault().post(busDisplayStatusFrameLayout);
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
            fragmentTransaction.remove(EventsFragment.this);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(tagName, 0);
```

with

```
Fragment eventsFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(getString(R.string.events_fragment));
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_work_table_fragment,
                            eventsFragment,
                            getString(R.string.events_fragment)).commit();//don't add to back stack again
```

onBackPressed

```
 @Override 
    public void doBackTabZero(String nameFragment) {
          android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(); 
          if(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1 ){
              fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(); 
          }else{
              super.onBackPressed();
          }
    }
```

Comment: I wrote backPress for fragment . when I click on back button get me error :           @Override
    public void doBackTabZero(String nameFragment) {android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
        fragmentTransaction.remove(EventsFragment.this);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();}   Here get me error :fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();

Comment: post back method in comment and what you need to do on clicking of back

Comment: When I click on back close the fragment like activity

Comment: @  rajan ks. I edited my source with your response but get me bellow error often :java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: SignsFragment{8aa2dfa #3 id=0x7f0a006e SignsFragment}